# Can I combine queries in SQL? I am trying to get a total revenue number. Here are the queries that I have

Tags: sql, sum

My project is a parking system for the school. To get the total revenue I will sum the permit price column:

```
select sum(permit.price) from permit;
```

Then to get the total violation revenue, I will get the ticket price for each type of violation (1), then multiply by the number of that type of violation(2,3, and 4)

1. ```
   select sum(violation_type.amount_due) from violation_type where violation_type_id = 1;
   ```
2. ```
   select count(Violation_Type_ID = '1') from violation where violation_type_id = '1';
   ```
3. ```
   select count(Violation_Type_ID = '2') from violation where violation_type_id = '2';
   ```
4. ```
   select count(Violation_Type_ID = '3') from violation where violation_type_id = '3';
   ```
5. ```
   select count(Violation_Type_ID = '4') from violation where violation_type_id = '4';
   ```

How would I put all this in 1 query? Thanks.

Comment: ~What have you tried so far?

Comment: add ***permit*** and ***violation*** tables structure and simple of raw data and query result data.

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as strings?

Comment: The answer depends on how you want the output to look. Do you want one record for each `violation_type_id` or one record that shows all totals, one column per `violation_type_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want everything summed in SQL then:

```
SELECT SUM(TotalAmount) AS TotalAmount
FROM (
      SELECT SUM(permit.price) AS TotalAmount 
      FROM permit

      UNION ALL

      SELECT SUM(vt.amount_due)
      FROM violation v
      JOIN violation_type vt
      ON v.violation_type_id = vt.violation_type_id

    ) as Sums
```

If you needed it broken down by violation type then it would be:

```
          SELECT v.violation_type,
          COUNT() [Count], 
          SUM(vt.amount_due) TotalAmount
          FROM violation v
          JOIN violation_type vt
          ON v.violation_type_id = vt.violation_type_id
          GROUP ON v.violation_type
```

If the one violation_type_id is a varchar instead of a number, then you would join like:

```
     ON CAST(v.violation_type_id AS INT) = vt.violation_type_id
```

Comment: Great. That worked. Thanks. I haven't learned about union at all yet. Can you tell me exactly what that is doing?

Comment: @IsaacC Great, don't forget to mark this as the correct answer so others will know.  UNION will combine result sets and remove duplicates. UNION ALL will combine without removing duplicates. Unions have to have the same number of columns.

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner but I also wanted to ask why are you able to substitute in v and vt for violation and violation type without saying "as" or putting in more code for that.

Comment: @IsaacC "as" is optional - I should have had that for my table aliases and my column aliases.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN vt.violation_type_id = '1' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) ViolationType1Count,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN vt.violation_type_id = '1' THEN vt.amount_due
        ELSE 0.0
    END) ViolationType1AmtDue,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN vt.violation_type_id = '2' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) ViolationType2Count,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN vt.violation_type_id = '2' THEN vt.amount_due
        ELSE 0.0
    END) ViolationType2AmtDue,
    etc.
FROM
    violation_type vt INNER JOIN
        violation v
    ON vt.violation_type_id = v.violation_type_id
```